# Валидация бинов

Tags: java, java-ee, junit

Вопрос по поводу следующего кода:

> assertEquals(1,constraintViolations.size());
>
> assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 14",
>   constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());

1.Не понятно почему сравнивается в строке assertEquals(1,constraintViolations.size());
с единицей?

Ведь сравнивается единица с длиной Set, если существует в сете ConsrtaintViolations то значит есть нарушения, какова логика при таком сравнении ?

2.Второй метод сравнивает равно ли `"size must be between 2 and 14"` с `constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage())`, то есть по сути равно ли

`"size must be between 2 and 14"` с `"size must be between 2 and 14"` ?

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = factory.getValidator();
}

@Test
public void licensePlateTooShort(){

    Car car = new Car("Moris","D", 4);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(car);

    assertEquals(1,constraintViolations.size());
    assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 14", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
}

public class Car {

public Car(String manufacturer, String licensePlate, int seatCount) {
    super();
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
}


public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}


public String getLicensePlate() {
    return licensePlate;
}


public int getSeatCount() {
    return seatCount;
}


@NotNull
private String manufacturer;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max= 14)
private String licensePlate;


@NotNull
@Min(2)
private int seatCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assertEquals(1,constraintViolations.size());
```

проверяет, что первый агрумент равен второму аргументу, т.е. `1 == constraintViolations.size()`

```
assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 14", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
```

проверяет, что `"size must be between 2 and 14" == constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()`, то есть они равны

`assertEquals()` использует метод `equals()`, если он определен. Таким образом, можно использовать свой принцип сравнения объектов. Если он не определен - работает как `assertSame()`.

`assertSame()` просто сравнивает объекты при помощи оператора `==`, то есть проверяет, являются ли параметры ссылками на один и тот же объект.

Хорошая статья [тут](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_using_assertion.htm)

Comment: 1. То есть если в первом 1 == 1 то есть Violation ? 

2. Не понятно насчёт сообшения... Откуда берется сообшение   "size must be between 2 and 14" в самом сете ConstraintViolation ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov если условие не срабатывает, то выбрасывается исключение, то есть, если 1 `constraintViolations.size() != 1` то выбросит исключение, 
тоже самое и во втором случае. проверяется, что текст ` "size must be between 2 and 14" ` , будет равен значению  первого элемента в `constraintViolations `

Comment: Из моего примера в коде.. 
При сравнении строки во втором случаи  "size must be between 2 and 14" и getMessage() сравнивается "size must be between 2 and 14" == "size must be between 2 and 14" ??

Comment: @Maks.Burkov  assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 14", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
проверяет, что `"size must be between 2 and 14" == constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()`, то есть они равны
__ то есть, мы проверяем, что они равны. я не знаю что лежит в  `constraintViolations[0].getMessage() `, я не знаю почему именно эту строку выбрали. я по факту говорю что происходит. в коде проверяется что равны, в противном случае - выбрасывается исключение

Comment: " Я не знаю почему именно эту строку выбрали" : Тут мне не понятно что будет взято с методом getMessage(), по логике вещей должна быть дана та же строка.. Откуда будет взята значение этой строки ? Ведь сравнивается  "size must be between 2 and 14" с getMessage() значением.. Если посмотреть на мой код CAR то он не содержит @Size(min = 2, max= 14, message = "size must be between 2 and 14"")

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода, который помог мне разобратся в логике валидации!

Может кому будет полезно, просто и ясно!

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class UserValidation {


@NotNull(message = "Can't be null")
String firstName;


@NotNull(message = "Can't be null")
@Size(min = 3 , message = "Need to be more then 3 characters")
String lastName;


public static void validate (Object object, Validator validator){

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(object);

    System.out.println(violations.size());

    for(ConstraintViolation<Object> violation: violations){

        System.out.println(violation.getMessage()+"  "+violation.getPropertyPath()+"  "+violation.getInvalidValue());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

     ValidatorFactory vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
     Validator validator = vf.getValidator();

     UserValidation user = new UserValidation();

     user.firstName = null;
     user.lastName = "MA";

     validate(user, validator);

}
}
```

=====================================================

```
2

Need to be more then 3 characters  lastName  MA

Can't be null  firstName  null
```